Problem 2, Chapter 2, First Course in Probability by Ross 10th ed.
I am currently self-studying Sheldon Ross' Intro to Probability and I am stuck on this problem. I've tried doing this but I'm not sure enumerating the possibilities. If anyone is patient enough to help, I'd be glad.
In a session, an archer shoots rounds of 3 arrows. The session is terminated when the target is hit with all three arrows in one round. Set up a set to serve as the sample space. Let $A_n$ denote the event comprising sessions with durations longer than n. Determine the event, $$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$$

Is the question just asking what the symbols represent physically?

What have you tried?
